# Requirment for Ghusl after Sexual Intercourse or Masturbation

Tags: sex, wudu, ghusl, masturbation

Is it permissible for a man to preform Wudhu instead of Ghusl in the case of sperm discharge either through masturbation or sex if preforming Ghusl over and over again difficult and can prompt suspicion.

Comment: my answer is "no", but i cannot write it because it is not allowed for its shortage.

Answer (score 1):

Ghusl (bath) is required after ejaculation to attain the ritual purity required for Salah (prayers). There is no excuse for avoiding it except the shortage of water or an illness which would be worsened by use of water ... in which case Tayammum (dry ablution) is permitted.

> يا أيها الذين آمنوا لا تقربوا الصلاة ... ولا جنبا ... حتى تغتسلوا وإن كنتم مرضى أو على سفر أو جاء أحد منكم من الغائط أو لامستم النساء فلم تجدوا ماء فتيمموا صعيدا طيبا فامسحوا بوجوهكم وأيديكم
>
> O you who have believed, **do not approach prayer
> while** ... **in a state of janabah**, ... **until you have washed
> (تَغْتَسِلُوا)** [your whole body]. And if you are ill or on a journey
> or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have
> contacted women and find no water, then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and your hands [with it]. ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:43](https://quran.com/4/43?translations=20)</sup>

> خروج المني عن شهوة دفقا من غير إيلاج بأي سبب حصل الخروج كاللمس، والنظر، والاحتلام، حتى يجب الغسل بالإجماع
>
> Ejaculation from the private part with desire, without coitus by any means such as touching or looking or a wet dream, makes it obligatory to perform ghusl, by consensus.
>
> <sup>— [Badaa'i' as-Sanaa'i'](https://shamela.ws/book/8183/35)</sup>

> اتفق الفقهاء على أن الغسل يجب بالاستمناء
>
> The jurists are agreed that ghusl becomes obligatory because of ejaculation due to masturbation
>
> <sup>— [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/2192)</sup>

When something is obligatory it is essential to do it and not optional. Inconvenience or embarrassment are irrelevant.

Note that in coitus, even penetration without ejaculation makes ghusl obligatory. However any other form of intimacy will not make ghusl obligatory unless it is accompanied by ejaculation.

Answer (score 0):

Ghusl (washing whole body) is obligatory not only after ejaculation but even without ejaculation if penis inserted in woman vagina once it becomes obligatory.

If case of shortage of water you can have Tayamum (dry ablution).